# How to group search by time field in a big data table of PgSQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

I group search data by type of time field of PGSQL. I except it can give me a result which contains the count of query and group by day. I used SQL sentence like

```sql
select t.createtime,
       count(1)
from my_table t
where t.createtime>'2021-06-01'
group by t.createtime;
```

Although I index field `createtime` in advance, it takes a lot of time as soon as the time range is large. Another point I noticed was that the index didn't seem to work when the date range was expanded. I try my best to deal with it, but it does not work.

Comment: PostgresSQL doesn't use T-SQL, that's SQL Server's/Sybase's dialect. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to group by minute, hour, day, week, etc., it's tempting to just group by your timestamp column, however, then you'll get one group per second, which is likely not what you want. Instead, you need to "truncate" your timestamp to the granularity you want, like minute, hour, day, week, etc.

```sql
select t.createtime('day', created_at),
       count(1)
from my_table t
where t.createtime>'2021-06-01'
group by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but what puzzles me is why the index is not used in the following explanation analysis after the time span is large. Is it because the group by is used for full-text index instead of BTREE index？